# Remote check if machine is alive and reachable using c# under NAT

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm trying to develop a "backup service" that should start if i can't reach a specific pc.

The backup service should check if the machine is alive (ping isn't a solution because the remote machine can be natted).

Maybe a failed ssh connection can tell me if the machine is down\not reachable.

The idea is:

```
 If (!EndPointIsAlive){
//start backup
}else{
//wait x and retry
}
```

Comment: Why should NAT be an argument against a ping? If an ICMP packet returns, you know that the network interface is up & running.
You just need to know the public address of the remote machine you want to check. If you are using a DNS server the ping could target the domain  as well. F.e.: fileserver1.thetargetdomain.net

Comment: if an icmp packet return i know that the router is up and running not the machine

Answer (score 0):

NAT is no argument against ping as I stated in my comment. 
In my oppionion you try to re-invent the wheel. I advise you to check the SNMP protocol and SNMP traps, which fulfill just you needs.

Traps are trigger based events which are sent to a management machine, where an alarm is raised.

You would instantly know, if and which machine just went down.